# Integral basis in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am missing something about this sentence from my number theory notes:
${1, \frac{1+ \sqrt{-3}}{2} }$ is an integral basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, so $x+y\sqrt{-3}$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ lies in $O_K$ if and only if $x+y$ and $x-y$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}$. I am probably missing something very easy but I don't see how to get to those constraints on the coefficients.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Integral_basis

Comment: Karl, do you know the definition of "integral basis"? if not, follow the previous link. I think it answers your question.

Comment: I corrected the typos. @AnneBauval, by the definition of integral basis, any linear comb. with integer coefficients of the basis elements is in $O_K$, so anything of the form $(a + \frac{b}{2})+ \sqrt{-3}\frac{b}{2}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes, so $x+y\sqrt{-3}$ is of this form iff $x,y$ are rationals and ... ?

Comment: oh f..........k. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, consider the set of algebraic numbers ($a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$):
$$a \cdot 1 + b \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} = \frac{2a+b+b\sqrt{-3}}{2} = x+y\sqrt{-3}$$
Hence $x=a+\frac{b}{2}$ and $y=\frac{b}{2}$ and thus clearly $x+y$ and $x-y$ are integers.

Conversely, if $x+y$ and $x-y$ are integers, say $x+y=c$ and $x-y=d$, then
$$x=\frac{c+d}{2}$$ and $$y=\frac{c-d}{2}$$
So
$$x+y\sqrt{-3} = \frac{c+d+(c-d)\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
which, for varying $c$ and $d$ is the same set as what we started with: $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$